# Quel équivalent français existe-t-il pour "Bare Metal" (ou "sans systèmes d'exploitation") ?

Tags: traduction, terminologie, informatique

Bonjour, je cherche une traduction possible pour "Bare Metal". Ou un mot pour décrire un système électronique (ou PC) sans systèmes d'exploitation, "à nu".

***Contexte***:
Je cherchais une puce électronique, mais le modèle voulu est toujours livré avec un mini système d'exploitation. D'où ma question:

Existe-t-il un terme (ou une combinaison de deux mots tout au plus) pour désigner cela de manière précise ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On parle de systèmes/serveurs **physiques** par opposition à systèmes/serveurs virtualisés.

*Bare metal* ne signifie pas pour moi qu'il n'y a pas de système d'exploitation, auquel cas ***système nu*** pourrait être utilisé, mais une plate-forme qui utilise directement et exclusivement le matériel, à l'opposée d'une plate-forme où plusieurs environnements (virtualisés) se partagent le même matériel.

Comment: Je ne l'avais jamais vu sous cette forme, mais ça fait sens.
Je voulais parlé des puces électroniques, qui sont parfois livré avec un OS real time, je cherchais un terme pour désigner sans OS. Je vais préciser mon post, merci de ta réponse en tout cas.

Comment: On parle parfois d'ordinateur nu, mais il n'y a pas plus nu qu'une puce ... Je ne vois pas à part : *Livré sans OS* voire *livré sans SE*. Sinon, pour les processeurs, on dit aussi parfois version *OEM* (nue) par rapport à version *boite* (complète). *OEM* n'est pas particulièrement français, mais est bien compris.

Comment: Je ne peux pas encore plussoyer, mais le coeur y est !
Merci beaucoup, j'avais oublié l'expression OEM !

Comment: Bare metal a aussi la signification supposée par @BuzzRage (signification qui date d'avant l'avénement de la virtalisation). Voir le sens 1 sur le [wiktionnaire anglais](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bare_metal). "système nu" ou "sans OS" me semble tout à fait approprié.

Comment: La notion d'utilisation directe du matériel est-elle différente de celle du _serveur dédié_ ? J'y connais rien mais disons que je veux louer une certaine capacité de traitement et de bande passante et j'ai vu un forfait et je montre ça à qqn. est-il possible que la personne m'oppose le _bare metal_ comme un avantage sur le partage d'une même « boîte » ou une personne dirait _ton propre serveur_ ? Merci !

Comment: @xhienne Oui, ça pourrait en effet convenir à ce qui était demandé dans la question originale. Le wiktionnaire décrit un système fonctionnel (matériel + logiciel) où le code interagit directement avec le matériel sans passer par les services d'un système d'exploitation. Après l'édition, j'ai quand même l'impression que BuzzRage cherche seulement le nom d'un processeur livré seul, pas le nom d'un système opérationnel.

Comment: @floquonsd'oùpepperx L'utilisation directe du matériel par les application est très rare sur un serveur hébergé. La couche "système d'exploitation" est toujours présente (sauf quand on développe un boot-loader, un moniteur ou un système d'exploitation lui-même). Un serveur dédié loué chez un hébergeur peut l'être avec ou sans OS pré-installé, mais une fois qu'il est en exploitation, il y a un OS. Sinon, on parle bien de *bare metal* pour serveur dédié (à un client) comparé à serveur virtuel, partagé entre plusieurs clients.

Comment: @floquonsd'oùpepperx La notion directe du matériel dans le cas évoqué par BuzzRage est typiquement celle d'un micro-système (ex: micro-contrôleur) où vous compilez votre programme et le "flashez" dans la mémoire permanente (EPROM) dudit système. Quand le système démarre, la première instruction exécutée est celle de votre programme (pas d'OS intermédiaire). On n'est pas du tout dans les mêmes échelles qu'un serveur dédié. Il s'agit ici d'informatique embarquée, celle qui se cache dans un lave-linge ou un réveil matin.

Comment: @jlliagre je cherchais plus précisément une devboard pour tester un processeur, mais tous semblaient être livré avec des composants inutiles dans ce que je veux en faire (HDMI, carte vidéo etc..), je voulais simplement le proco, un JTAG et des GPIO, sans OS. Mais le mot que je cherchais concernait surtout la partie "sans OS", sans couche d'abstraction (ce n'est pas nécessaire, voire encombrant dans le projet que je développe).

Comment: Merci @xhienne pour le lien wiktionnaire, faut que je prenne le réflexe de regarder là si wordreference ne me satisfait pas ! 
Et oui, j'aurais du précisé mais je parlais bien de système embarqués, où les ressources sont limités et où il est parfois, sur des gros projets, nécessaire d'outrepasser les OS quand il y en a (petits linux pour les grosses puces, FreeRTOS etc..).